# Is protractor e2e enough for angularJS testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, test-coverage

I am new to testing and AngularJS and I have a task to test a very complex AngularJS project and the backend of the app as well.
Currently I have e2e test running with protractor that cover every possible scenario in terms of input/actions and output/results. Is this enough? I need to achieve a good test coverage for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript testing is covered by Jasmine and all of its flavors.

**End to end testing**

For e2e testing you can use ***[Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/toc)*** which is the recommended framework.

**Unit Testing**

For Unit testing, you should use ***[Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html)***, 
or ***[mocha](http://mochajs.org/)*** (serial).

**Backend testing**

You said that you need to test backend. I would recommend to make tests directly to backend endpoints/functions, simulating use cases and expecting the appropiate correct results, to ensure you're covering every aspect of the app. This will depend on what language/framework you have your backend.

So, the answer is NO, Protractor is not enough.

**Why write tests?**

Basically, the reason you write tests is to keep your code working together correctly, and to ensure the "contracts" between functions and each connections you have between backend-frontend, backend-backend, and frontend-frontend work correctly. So, every time you modify a portion of the code, you don't have to check every part of the code to find a bug, and also you have a really clear idea what part of your code is failing.